# Equivalent of add-face-text-property for overlays?

Tags: faces, overlays

`add-face-text-property` is very convenient for adjusting the face of text based on text properties ([Changing Text Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html)).

**Q:** Is there an existing equivalent to `add-face-text-property` to add face properties to *overlays*?

Otherwise something like this should be sufficient (and maybe should be a feature request):

```
(defun my/add-face-overlay-property (overlay face &optional append)
  "Add the face property to OVERLAY.  FACE specifies the face to add.
It should be a valid value of the `face' property (typically a
face name or a plist of face attributes and values).

If the overlay already has a non-nil `face' property, those
face(s) are retained.  This is done by setting the `face'
property to a list of faces, with FACE as the first element (by
default) and the pre-existing faces as the remaining elements.

If optional fourth argument APPEND is non-nil, append FACE to the end
of the face list instead."
  (overlay-put overlay 'face
               (if (plist-member overlay 'face)
                   (if append
                       (list (plist-get overlay 'face) face)
                     (list face (plist-get overlay 'face)))
                 face)))
```

Comment: `M-: (info "(elisp)overlays")` does not mention such a function. You can search for all occurences in that section by `C-s`.

Also `describe-function` (`C-h f`) with search terms `*overlay*face` and `*face*overlay` does not reveal anything related.